# Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types. Hope for assistance

Tags: java, constructor, bluej

I'm fairly new to `Java` and I'm using `BlueJ`. I keep getting the error:

```
constructor ItemNotFound in class ItemNotFound cannot be applied to given types;
required: int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length
```

I'm fairly confused and in turn not sure how to fix the problem. Hopefully someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Here is my class Catalog:

```
public class Catalog {
    private Item[] list;
    private int size;

    // Construct an empty catalog with the specified capacity.
    public Catalog(int max) {
        list = new Item[max];
        size = 0;
    }

    // Insert a new item into the catalog.
    // Throw a CatalogFull exception if the catalog is full.
    public void insert(Item obj) throws CatalogFull {
        if (list.length == size) {
            throw new CatalogFull();
        }
        list[size] = obj;
        ++size;
    }

    // Search the catalog for the item whose item number
    // is the parameter id.  Return the matching object 
    // if the search succeeds.  Throw an ItemNotFound
    // exception if the search fails.
    public Item find(int id) throws ItemNotFound {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < size; ++pos){
            if (id == list[pos].getItemNumber()){
                return list[pos];
            }
            else {
                throw new ItemNotFound(); //"new ItemNotFound" is the error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, here is the code for the `class ItemNotFound` as well:

```
// This exception is thrown when searching for an item
// that is not in the catalog.
public class ItemNotFound extends Exception {
    public ItemNotFound(int id) {
        super(String.format("Item %d was not found.", id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ItemNotFound` class only has one constructor: one that takes an `int` parameter:

```
public ItemNotFound(int id)
```

You're trying to call that without any arguments:

```
throw new ItemNotFound();
```

That's not going to work - you need to pass an argument for that parameter. I suspect you just want:

```
throw new ItemNotFound(id);
```

(Given that the `id` parameter to the `find` method is the ID you're looking for.)

Additionally, I'd recommend that you rename your exception to include a suffix of `Exception` to follow Java naming conventions - so `ItemNotFoundException`.

You'll *also* need to change your loop - currently you're throwing an exception if the *first* value doesn't have the right ID, whereas presumably you want to loop through all of them. So your `find` method should look like this:

```
public Item find(int id) throws ItemNotFoundException {
    for (int pos = 0; pos < size; ++pos){
        if (id == list[pos].getItemNumber()){
            return list[pos];
        }
    }
    throw new ItemNotFoundException(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You provided a custom constructor to your class  `ItemNotFound`  and not passing the required arguments  when you are using it.

Try to pass required args here

```
  throw new ItemNotFound(id);
```

So your code becomes

```
public Item find(int id) throws ItemNotFound {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < size; ++pos){
            if (id == list[pos].getItemNumber()){
                return list[pos];
            }
            else {
                throw new ItemNotFound(id); //  Now constructor satisfied
            }
        }
    }
```

And

```
throw new ItemNotFound();
```

That above line is true when your class     `ItemNotFound`  is like

```
// This exception is thrown when searching for an item
// that is not in the catalog.
public class ItemNotFound extends Exception {
    public ItemNotFound() {
        super("Sorry !! No item find with that id"); //Now a generic message.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

throw new Item() is not valid as an explicit constructor has been defined Item(int id).

Comment: Please come again. I didn't understand how this is related to the question.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I thought you were passing an int argument to the constructor :  super(String.format("Item %d was not found.", id)); which is present in catalog class.  Actually, throe new Item() is not valid as you have defined an explicit constructor item(int id)...Pleasse ignore my previous answer.

Comment: Edit your answer and post it there. Not here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided a constructor without any parameters.

```
public ItemNotFound()
```

and you are calling `new ItemNotFound(id)` which while creating instance of class ItemNotFound expects a constructor with `one parameter of type int`. So you need to have an overloaded constructor

```
public class ItemNotFound extends Exception {
    public ItemNotFound() {
        super("Sorry !! No item find with that id"); //Now a generic message.
    }

    public ItemNotFound(int if) {
        this(); //Since you are not using any int id in this class
    }
}
```