# Method cannot be applied to given types. Hope for assistance

Tags: java, methods, bluej

I'm fairly new to `Java` and I'm using `BlueJ`. I keep getting the error:

```
method find in class Catalog cannot be applied to given types;
required: int
found: Item
reason: actual argument Item cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion
```

I'm very confused and in turn not sure how to fix the problem. Hopefully someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Here is my Program2 class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        Catalog store = new Catalog(3);
        int itemnum;
        Item item;

        try {
            store.insert
              (new Music(1111, "Gold", 12.00, "Abba"));
            store.insert
              (new Movie(2222, "Mamma Mia", 16.00, "Meryl Streep"));
            store.insert
              (new Book(3333, "DaVinci Code", 8.00, "Dan Brown"));
              store.insert
            (new Music(4444, "Legend", 15.00, "Bob Marley"));
            } catch (CatalogFull exc) {
                System.out.println(exc);
            }

        //  Insert code here to perform a sequence of
        //  interactive transactions with the user.
        //  The user enters an item number and the program
        //  either displays the item or prints an error message
        //  if the item is not found.  The program terminates
        //  when the user enters zero as the item number.

        while (!item.equals("0")) {
            itemnum = store.find(item); //Getting error on ".find"
            if (itemnum != null) {
                System.out.print(itemnum);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s was not found.%n", item);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Player (0 to exit)? ");
            item = kbd.next();
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, here is the `class Catalog` as well:

```
public class Catalog {
    private Item[] list;
    private int size;

    // Construct an empty catalog with the specified capacity.
    public Catalog(int max) {
        list = new Item[max];
        size = 0;
    }

    // Insert a new item into the catalog.
    // Throw a CatalogFull exception if the catalog is full.
    public void insert(Item obj) throws CatalogFull {
        if (list.length == size) {
            throw new CatalogFull();
        }
        list[size] = obj;
        ++size;
    }

    // Search the catalog for the item whose item number
    // is the parameter id.  Return the matching object 
    // if the search succeeds.  Throw an ItemNotFound
    // exception if the search fails.
    public Item find(int id) throws ItemNotFound {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < size; ++pos){
            if (id == list[pos].getItemNumber()){
                return list[pos];
            }
        }
        throw new ItemNotFound(id);
        }
}
```

Comment: You try to put `Item` as `int`, so where is `Item` definition? I'm sure it should be something like `store.find(item.getId())` or `store.find(item.id)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types. Hope for assistance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109545/constructor-in-class-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types-hope-for-assistance)

Comment: @SubirKumarSao  I'l slightly disagree. Both are different questions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `find()` method  signature here

```
   public Item find(int id) throws ItemNotFound {
```

receives  int as argument.But you are passing `Item` object

```
itemnum = store.find(item);
```

You just have to reverse it

```
 item= store.find(itemnum);
```

That means

`item`  is assigned  by finding with the id  `itemnum`, since your find method returning `Item` object.

Answer (score 0):

Change `itemnum = store.find(item)` to `item = store.find(itemnum)`.